# How do you add a hint/description for Android custom properties/attributes?

Tags: android, view, attributes, android-custom-view

I'm working on various custom views and I expect to have quite a number of sometime unclear properties or attributes. I would like to add a description to my own, just like the stock View are being described.

The top image doesn't have hint/description, while the Android stock ones have.

[image]

Comment: Do you define the attributes in code? Then try adding a javadoc on top of the attribute method.

Comment: Ah! Just figured it out. ADT simply simply uses a xml comment just above.
    <declare-styleable name="BackgroundView">
        
        <attr name="backGroundGradientFromColor"    format="color"     />
        <attr name="backGroundGradientToColor"      format="color"     />        
        <attr name="roundedBorderShadow"            format="boolean"   />
        
        <!-- Whether or not the 'interior' part of will be drawn by this View subclass -->
        <attr name="drawBackground"                 format="boolean"   />        
    </declare-styleable>

Comment: Lurked the internet for a good hour about this, you should definitely put it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip Stephan, I'm not a big 'social networker'